# devise recaptcha not reachable

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, recaptcha

i try to use recaptcha on devise. Every time when i put the code in racaptcha and submit the form, i receive the message "recaptcha-not-reachable". A few days ago the recaptcha works fine  but now i receive always the message "recaptcha-not-reachable", i really don't know why.

view

```html
<div class="password">

  <p class="forgot">Forgot your password?</p>

  <hr class="style-six">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="email">
      <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => {:id => "renew", :class => "form-horizontal", :method => :post }) do |f| %>

          <div class="control-group mailinput">
            <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email", :autofocus => true, :required => true %>
          </div>

          <%= recaptcha_tags :display => { :theme => 'white' } %>

          <div class="control-group">
            <%= f.button "Re-new password", :class => "btn btn-primary"  %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

controller

```ruby
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  layout 'xxxx_layout'

  # POST /resource/password
  def create
    if verify_recaptcha
      self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)
      if successfully_sent?(resource)
        respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
      else
        flash.delete :recaptcha_error
        flash.now[:error] = t("error.user.noexist")
        render "passwords/new"
      end
    else
      build_resource
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code."
      #flash.delete :recaptcha_error
      render "passwords/new"
    end
  end

end
```

root

```ruby
get 'password/new' => 'passwords#new', :as => :new_user_password
post 'password'    => 'passwords#create', :as => :user_password
get 'password/edit' => 'passwords#edit', :as => :edit_user_password
put 'password' => 'passwords#update'
```

/config/initializers/recaptcha.rb

```ruby
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key  = 'xxxxxxx'
  config.private_key = 'xxxxxxx'
  config.proxy = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
end
```

config/application.rb

```ruby
require "net/http"
```

Answer (score 0):

`config.proxy = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'` seems to be wrong. That is usually the Adress your development server uses, so there can't be a proxy. Change this to your real proxy or comment it out.

As it is now, reCAPTCHA tries to establish a connection to recaptcha-servers using your rails-app as a proxy. Your rails-app doesn't understand the request (you should probably see something in your logs!) and returns an error-page. Now recaptcha tries to parse that response but doesn't know how to read it or even recognizes that this is not from recaptcha server and complains about not being able to reach its servers.